# Why Do I get "wp_remote-get: could not handle for fopen()"?

Tags: plugins, css

I'm trying to get an image from Google but...

wp_remote_get returns me:

```
Could not open handle for fopen() to 
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?
v=1.0&q=whatever.whatever&key=MYKEYWHICHIDONTPOST&userip=127.0.0"
```

I don't know why:

- when I enter the url directly I do get results.
- all other wp_remote_gets in the same class work ok so yes php.ini allow=ok

this is the code i run:

```
$referer_url = get_bloginfo('url');
$referer = $parsed_url[host];                   
$google_images_url = self::GOOGLE_IMAGES_URL . "&q=" .  $url_to_look_for . "&key=" . $key . "&userip="  . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$response = wp_remote_get($google_images_url, array( 'headers' => array( 'Referer' => $referer)));
```

hmmm

Comment: ah... it is the https ... doesnt like that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, I experienced that under some network configurations `https` links fail (my case was behind proxy server).

You can use [Core Control](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/core-control/) plugin to test available HTTP transports and disable glitchy one. In my case bumping transport to curl solved issue.